# Progress open edge - Adding Index

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

I'm very new to progress, I have added an Index in my DBserver, I'm unable to view the added index  in my progress development tool (eclipse). It is not showing my updated DB changes. Any help appreciated!!

Comment: Do you have access to the regular Data Dictionary? Can you see it there?

Comment: What steps did you take to add the index?  Why do you think they were successful?